# Application windows suddenly become inactive - Macbook M1

Tags: macos

I noticed (for a couple of months now) that my application windows (i.e. Safari, Brave browser, Evernote) become inactive and I have to click in the window to make it active again.

It is as if something is *clicking* outside the window to make something else active. But I don't see anything in the Finder that becomes active.

This is vert frustrating because (for instance) when I'm typing something I have to click in the window to make Safari active again. How can this happen and is there a fix for it?

I'm using Big Sur (11.4) with an Apple M1 8gig. Thanks! <3

Comment: Does the app still show in the Menu bar? Do you have more than one window open for an app… & are these across more than one Space?

Comment: Yes it says (in this example) Safari in the menubar. I have only one open window :-)

Comment: Then I really can't think of any reason. If the app is frontmost & there's only one window, there is literally nothing that could remove focus from it, excapt perhaps a pop-up which is not showing in front. If you use Spaces, flip around to other Spaces & see if it's popped one on another Space. You may need to move other windows out of the way to see if something has popped up behind. [My partner, who uses Spaces… but badly… often gets this type of issue. One day, I'll get her to properly lock apps to Spaces, but 15 years & no joy so far;))